# Get the date of a dump file from mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have created a MySQL database from a .sql dump file. I have lost the dump file, but I want to know when that dump was taken. Is it possible to know when the dump was taken from the MySQL database? If possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the general log enabled at the time of the dump, then there will be a record. But otherwise, no, there isn't a record in the database.

You could look at things like shell history, or ssh logins, but its unlikely to yield any specific results.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to find the log?

Comment: If you don't have `general-log` set in your MySQL configuration file(s) it doesn't exist (under `/etc/my*`)). If it does, it points to where to find it.

Comment: Ok, I don't think I had set it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The slowlog, if turned on, might have clues -- since the bigger SELECTs were probably recorded there.